# JavaScript not triggering events when dynamically loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, element, swiper.js

I'm using the Swiper.js library and I have an issue getting the 'slideChange' event to trigger when dynamically loading elements through JavaScript.

Here is where my swipers both horizontal and vertical are initialised:

```js
var swiper = {
    initialize : function() {
        swiperH = new Swiper('.swiper-container-h', {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            preloadImages: false,
            updateOnImagesReady: true,
            lazy: true,
        })
        .on('slideChange', function () {
            console.log('Swiped Horizonally');
        });

        swiperV = new Swiper('.swiper-container-v', {
            direction: 'vertical',
            slidesPerView: 1,
            preloadImages: false,
            updateOnImagesReady: true,
            lazy: true,
            effect: 'fade',
            loop: true,
            fadeEffect: {
                crossFade: true
            },
            pagination: {
                el: '.swiper-pagination-v',
                clickable: true,
            },
        })
        .on('slideChange', function () {
            console.log('Swiped Vertically');
        });
    }
};
```

The reason why the horizontal's 'slideChange' triggers is because its already in the html file:

```html
   <!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="dash-container">
       <div class="swiper-container swiper-container-h">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper" id="swipeData">

       </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now, the vertical slides are loading through JavaScript and that's where the vertical's 'slideChange' doesn't trigger.

```js
function loadDresses(selectedDresses) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $('#swipeData').html('');

        for (var i = 0; i < selectedDresses.length; i++) {
            var vScroll = '<div class="swiper-slide"><div class="swiper-container swiper-container-v"><div class="swiper-wrapper" style="height: 100%;">';

            for (var j = 0; j < selectedDresses[i].images.length; j++) {
                vScroll += '<div class="swiper-slide"><img src="' + selectedDresses[i].images[j] + '"/></div>';
            }

            vScroll += '<div class="swiper-slide" style="display:table;height:100%;width:100%;">';
            vScroll += '</div></div></div><div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-v">';

            $('#swipeData').append(vScroll).trigger('create');
        }

        resolve(true);
    });
}
```

The error occurs at this snippet:

```
    .on('slideChange', function () {
        console.log('Swiped Vertically');
    });
```

[image: With this error]

Any ideas? Thanks!

Edit:

I have tried the following to stop it from initialising too early, but still no luck:

```
          loadDresses(dresses).then(function(result) {
            var t = setInterval(() => {
                swiper.initialize();
                clearInterval(t);
            }, 5000);
        });
```

Comment: According to the documentation, that call should work: https://swiperjs.com/api/#events. Check you're using the latest version of the plugin

Comment: It works when i add the vertical slider to the html instead of dynamically adding through javaScript :(, so the plugin is fine.

Comment: In that case you're probably calling `swiper.initialize()` too early. Make sure you do it after the promise is resolved.

Comment: loadDresses(dresses).then(function(result) {
                resolve(true);

                var t = setInterval(() => {
                    swiper.initialize();
                    clearInterval(t);
                }, 5000);
            }); - I've enabled a timer of 5 seconds, still not working.

Comment: Remove the `resolve(true)` in there, that should already have happened, and that would be causing an error in that context. Get rid of the timer. You don't need it if the promise is working properly. Ignore anyone who suggests that as a solution

Comment: Sorry that delay was in another promise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And doesn't that help?

```
var swiper = {
    initialize : function() {
        swiperH = new Swiper('.swiper-container-h', {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            preloadImages: false,
            updateOnImagesReady: true,
            lazy: true,
        })
        .on('slideChange', function () {
            console.log('Swiped Horizonally');
        });

        swiperV = new Swiper('.swiper-container-v', {
            direction: 'vertical',
            slidesPerView: 1,
            preloadImages: false,
            updateOnImagesReady: true,
            lazy: true,
            effect: 'fade',
            loop: true,
            fadeEffect: {
                crossFade: true
            },
            pagination: {
                el: '.swiper-pagination-v',
                clickable: true,
            },
            on: {
                slideChange: function() {
                    console.log('Swiped Vertically');
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: It triggers now, but i cannot get any of the swiperV's properties such as activeIndex and any of the others according to the documentations, it just returns undefined?

Comment: Can you send me all your solution by https://codesandbox.io/?

Answer (score 1):

You have some options here:

To keep the flow of your application, you can destroy the slider and reinitialize it.

```js
swiperH.destroy()
```

then

```js
loadDresses();
swiper.initialize();
```

OR

you can just `mySwiper.update()` every time you change your slide manually

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, the loadDresses() function resolves a promise, which then initialises the swipers. I have tried setting 5 second delays, still no luck. All of the horizontals properties work such as slide fade, loop, pagination etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that an element with class swiper-pagination-v is not found during initialization.

You can make condition for class swiper-pagination-v exists.

```
var swiper = {
    initialize : function() {
        swiperH = new Swiper('.swiper-container-h', {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            preloadImages: false,
            updateOnImagesReady: true,
            lazy: true,
        })
            .on('slideChange', function () {
                console.log('Swiped Horizonally');
            });

        if ($('.swiper-container-v').length > 0) {
            swiperV = new Swiper('.swiper-container-v', {
                direction: 'vertical',
                slidesPerView: 1,
                preloadImages: false,
                updateOnImagesReady: true,
                lazy: true,
                effect: 'fade',
                loop: true,
                fadeEffect: {
                    crossFade: true
                },
                pagination: {
                    el: '.swiper-pagination-v',
                    clickable: true,
                },
            })
                .on('slideChange', function () {
                    console.log('Swiped Vertically');
                });
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I have tried setting a delay of 5 seconds before initialising but still doesn't trigger. All of the vertical properties work such as fade scroll, loop, etc, so the class name does exist, just not the slideChange event.